# How to send my javascript variables in to a html form?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to write a small site to get my location and add some variables myself and later save this data in my database. The problem is that i cant sent in the data from my variables in javascript to my form in html. Everything else works except this..

Im trying to pass the values of mylat, mylong and myacc to the three hidden felds in my form. Any suggestion on how for a non coder?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>


    <!-- Geolocation API, to bad accuracy -->

    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>



    <script>

      x = navigator.geolocation;
      x.getCurrentPosition( success, failure, options );

      var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 30000,
        maximumAge: 30000 // If "0", new positions will be demanded
      };

      function success(position){

        //Fetch coordinates
        var mylat = position.coords.latitude;
        var mylong = position.coords.longitude;
        var myacc = position.coords.accuracy;
        $('#lat').html(mylat);
        $('#long').html(mylong);
        $('#acc').html(myacc);

        //Google-API-Ready latitude and longitue

        var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(mylat, mylong);

        //Setting up our Google map

        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 16,
          center: coords,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
          }

        //Creating the map

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        //Create a marker

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: coords});

      }

      function failure(){
        $('body').append("<p> Koordinater kunde inte läsas in </p> ");

      }


    </script>

    <style>

      #map {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
      }

    </style>
    <p>Latitude : </p><div id="lat"></div>
    <p>Longitude : </p><div id="long"></div>
    <p>Accuracy (m): </p><div id="acc"></div>


  <body>


      <form name="form" action="x-form.php" method="POST" />


      <input type="hidden" name="Latitude" id="Latitude" value="'+window.mylat+'"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="Longitude" id="Longitude"  value="'+window.mylong+'"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="Accuracy" id="Accuracy" value="'+window.myacc+'"/>


      <p>Antal :<br>
        <input type="number" name="Number" min="0" max="500" /></p>
      <br>
      <p>Höjd :<br>
        <input type="double" name="Hight" min="0.0" max="50.0" />
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Skicka" />

    </form>


    <!-- Placeholder map -->
    <div id="map">

    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your Latitude, Longitude and Accuracy paragraphs (`<p>` tags) and the cooresponding `div` elements are not within the `<body>` tag, so they won't show.

Comment: Sorry for not beeing clear. I want my values from:

var mylat = position.coords.latitude;
        var mylong = position.coords.longitude;
        var myacc = position.coords.accuracy;

to be sent to the value of:

<input type="hidden" name="Latitude" id="Latitude" value="'+window.mylat+'"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="Longitude" id="Longitude"  value="'+window.mylong+'"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="Accuracy" id="Accuracy" value="'+window.myacc+'"/> The <p> tags i just for me to see the values when developing. @JackA.

Comment: I submitted an answer to the hidden inputs question. I'd also strongly recommend that you fix your HTML formatting. There should be nothing between the `</head>` and `<body>` tags. The styles should go in the head and the JavaScript can go in either the head or body.

Comment: Thanks @JackA. Ill clean the code but right now i just mess around to understand everything better and to make it work. 

Solved it with a friends by using:

$('#Latitude')[0].value = mylat;
        $('#Longitude')[0].value = mylong;
        $('#Accuracy')[0].value = myacc;

Comment: Something like `$('#Latitude')[0].value = mylat` is bypassing jQuery and using the native browser object (that's what the `[0]` does). If you don't want to use jQuery, you can do it like this: `document.getElementById('Lattitude').value = mylat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery `val` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the values of inputs. In your case, you can set them in the same place where you are setting the display values, like so:

```
$('#Latitude').val(mylat);
$('#Longitude').val(mylong);
$('#Accuracy').val(myacc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in assigning value. I am using input type 'name' instead of 'id'

```
document.forms['form']['Latitude'].value=mylat; 
document.forms['form']['Longitude'].value=mylong; 
document.forms['form']['Accuracy'].value=myacc;
```

Instead of

```
$('#lat').html(mylat);
$('#long').html(mylong);
$('#acc').html(myacc);
```